# How to clear a sitecore rendering cache programatically

Tags: publishing, caching, html-caching

How can I clear an individual rendering cache from my site `on publishing` `Sitecore  item` programmatically. I followed below article which did not work for me.

[Clear individual Rendering/Component Html cache](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/17077/clear-individual-rendering-component-html-cache)

Comment: Which Sitecore version?

Comment: it's sitecore 9.3

Comment: Maybe try this then? https://medium.com/@markgibbons25/a-smarter-sitecore-html-cache-clearer-7da0b0da2793

Comment: htmlCache.RemoveKeysContaining(item.Paths.FullPath); is not working

Comment: You're using `Sitecore.Publishing.SmartHtmlCacheClearer`?

Comment: So is clearing the cache for the entire site working, just not individual renderings? What value does `preventHtmlCacheClear` have on the site definition?

Comment: we dont have preventHtmlCacheClear this attribute in the site definition. by default it will set to true only right?

Comment: If you do not have it then the HtmlCache should get cleared on publish, is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend after publish to clear caches from the whole site to make sure there are no caches left. This also clears component level caches. Here is an example code how to achieve this:

```
var context = SiteContext.GetSite(site.Name);
if (context != null && context.CacheHtml)
{
     context.Caches?.HtmlCache?.Clear();
}
```

You can hook to publishEnd like this:

```
  <event name="publish:end">
        <handler type="namespace.HtmlCacheClearer, DLLFileName" method="ClearCache" />
      </event>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. It's not working for us. could you please suggest any other idea. Also we do not want to delete site cache in every publish.

Comment: Note that this happens automatically in Sitecore 9.3 unless you set `preventHtmlCacheClear` to false on site definition. Unless your CD is on the same box as CA something like this also needs to run on `publish:end:remote` event